# How to create EditText numeric (signed and unsigned decimal) from java code

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

this is a loop that creates a table of EditText and I wish they were numerical

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

tableRow = new TableRow(this); //oggetto di tipo tableRow
tableRow.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

for (int j = 0; j < 3 ; j++) {

values[i][j] = new EditText(this);
values[i][j].setText(" " + array[count]);
values[i][j].setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);//spaziatura di ogni cella per i quattro lati
tableRow.addView(values[i][j]);
count++;
}

tableLayout.addView(tableRow);  
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
values[i][j].setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

you can use the above line of code

Update try the below and thier combination

I've tried combining flags (in desperation to see if it would work):

```
values[i][j].setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
values[i][j].setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL)
values[i][j].setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED)
```

refer this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html) for more inputtypes

Comment: but does not take the signed number and float number

Comment: I solved the problem with only one line of code:


valore[i][j].setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED                 | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);  thanks